# Direction (LTR/RTL): What's the difference between the CSS direction and HTML direction attribute?

Tags: html, css

Is there any difference between

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

and

```
<body style="direction:rtl">
```

?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`<body dir="rtl">` is more appropriate as per W3C recommendation:

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup

> Because directionality is an integral part of the document structure, markup should be used to set the directionality for a document or chunk of information, or to identify places in the text where the Unicode bidirectional algorithm alone is insufficient to achieve desired directionality. [...] You should therefore use dedicated bidi markup whenever it is available. Do not simply attach CSS styling to a general element to achieve the effect.

User-agents that ignore CSS will also benefit from this approach.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but a combination of both methods can give some styling power. For example you can (using CSS) float an element left or right depending on the class (.ltr or .rtl)

Comment: Once you have the html attribute, you don't need a class. You can use attribute selectors like `[dir=rtl]`, `:not([dir])`