# Hebrew Typography

Tags: css, font-face, hebrew, typography

I am working on a site which in in hebrew language. I added necessary hebrew font famuly and it's shows. But the problem is English language starts from left side and hebrew language is starts from right side. I used "text-align: right" for this. But the contents is not showing properly. Letter starts from left. How can i fix this to starts letter from right?

This site has also Contains English language in the footer.

Please can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Here is the link- http://demo.nameinto.net/afarsec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1. CSS's `direction` property

CSS has a [`direction` property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/direction) which you can use to set the text to render as `rtl` (right to left):

```
p {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

### Option 2. HTML's `dir` attribute

Alternatively you can set the [global `dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) on an HTML element:

```
<p dir="rtl"> ... </p>
```

Comment: The second one is the correct one. Set it on your `html` tag.

Comment: @Blackboy Yes, you should set the text direction on your whole document. CSS is for different purposes. From the reference link: "*Add dir="rtl" to the html tag any time the overall document direction is right-to-left. This sets the base direction for the whole document.*"  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375799/direction-ltr-rtl-whats-the-difference-between-css-direction-and-html-direct

Comment: You can override it back to `ltr` for left-to-right language on a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

To handle "bidirectional" (AKA "right to left") languages such as Hebrew, there should be command codes to set "RTL" (right to left) display. I presume you're using UTF-8 as your encoding, which includes LTR and RTL codes.

Note that for embedded LTR languages such as English (to put an English phrase in the middle of a Hebrew sentence), you have to switch to LTR and then back to RTL, so that the English renders left to right.