# CSS pseudo :dir(); :host-context() and directionality based styling

Tags: css, web-component, custom-element

In this question I'm looking for the cleanest possible solution for the problem below, along with urging the browsers' coders to catch up with the spec, especially `:dir()` one!!

**The problem** and it's current best known to me solution:

I'd like to style the image below based on **directionality**, flipping it, for example, when in RTL mode. The image resides in a shadow DOM. As of now, I'm achieving that with the styling below.

```html
::shadowRoot
    <style>
        .directed-image:dir(rtl) { transform: rotateY(180deg); }    -- Firefox only as of now
        :host-context([dir=rtl]) { transform: rotateY(180deg); }    -- Chromium only as of now
    </style>

    <img class="directed-image" src="..." />
```

**Issues** yet to be solved:

- None of the styles above helping **Safari**: it has not yet implemented `:dir()` pseudo class and it's people seems to have a [strong objection](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160038) to `:host-context()`
- I'm really not fan of those double-done solutions for a platform's diversity; would like to get rid of those, but this is only a secondary concern

**Solutions** ?:

The best I'd wish to have is that `:dir()` will get wide cross browser support - it'll solve the **Safari**'s issue as well as would provide a truly directionality context aware styling (downsides of `[dir=ltr]` are touched a bit in the WebKit's bug link above).

But given that

- [Chromium's bug on `:dir()`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576815) is staled from 2018
- [WebKit's bug on `:dir()`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64861) last touched at 2016!!!
- [Firefox's bug on `:host-context()`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1082060) is staled from 2018 with some concerns about the spec
- and unwillingness of WebKit to implement `:host-context()`

-- having all this: is there any other solution for the problem (looking to solve the **Safari** issue at first priority).

> JS based solutions are interesting but much less preferred.

Comment: `[dir=rtl]` would cover all HTML tags with `dir='rtl'` attributes and using a class such as `.rtl {direction: rtl}` should cover the rest...or am I missing something? Better yet a selector like `[dir=rtl], .rtl` would work.

Comment: Assume that user switches the language within the site (I have my own library to do that on the fly, no new site reload needed). The relevant `dir='ltr'` is set on the `body` of course. Now, non `:host-context` able browsers can't match that from within the `shadowRoot`. Class appliance dynamically as per lang. switch (a) requires JS; (b) still won't be matched unless going over each and every shadow host and applying the class directly + using `:host(.rtl)` within the shadow...

Comment: Is the img a custom `[is]`? Why is it in the `shadowRoot`?

Comment: It is just an example, but in this specific case: (a) no, it is not __customized__ (that's the right term) element, (b) it is in `shadow` since my use case is to style it while being __inside__ my custom component.

Comment: `[is]` as in the attribute assigned to a standard tag (ex `<img>`) so it can be treated as a *customized **built-in** element* (that's the correct term). If you need a more encompassing style scope that applies to all Shadow DOM, then gather all `<link>` and `<style>` tags using [`DocumentOrShadowRoot.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets). Shadow DOM API is still impractical. When I was starting out and was struggling with styles that bled from the back end application, style encapsulation appealed to me but that's trivial now.

Comment: The correction about the term accepted, you are right, thanks. Regarding the rest: practicality of the shadow DOM APIs is out of this scope; saying `styleSheets` is like to say - go JS path, I try to escape that (and even if I do go that way, `styleSheets` is not enough, it won't reflect `dir=rtl` on the `html`, for example).

Comment: Why not `html { direction: rtl }`? I don't see the difference vs. `<html dir='rtl'>`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375799/direction-ltr-rtl-whats-the-difference-between-the-css-direction-and-html-di) and W3C recommendation there. But we are derailing from the topic here.

Comment: As you said: the ``dir`` attribute on the ``body`` tag will (in most cases) be the **only** indication of a language change. Since CSS doesn't cascade (as you said) The only option **for now** is for Elements to observe that attribute change. So I *__fear__* your only option is a MutationObserver (in the elements you own)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman: would you like to publish your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted one? I'm doing as you said - starting MutationObserver in each custom element that needs to react on `dir` change and set the relevant class on the element self; while CSS is handling the rest via something like `:host(.rtl) {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**january 2020 answer**:

As you said: the `dir` attribute on the `body` tag will (in most cases) be the only indication of a language change. Since CSS doesn't cascade (yet; as you said) the only option **for now** is for Elements to observe that attribute change. So I fear your only option is a **MutationObserver** (in the elements you own)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false };
```

Comment: I'm also adding `attributeFilter: ['dir']` to the config object, FWIW. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could use [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/index.html). It's a CSS framework that allows you to easily switch between and create RTL and LTR stylesheets, without having to do too much double work.

It also supports a couple of big CSS frameworks if you use those, like Bootstrap and Semantic-UI

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I've went over the library and must say that my personal opinion about the architectural design decision taken by that lib is a wrong path: IMHO it imposes ever needed technical debt of maintenance and support for an initially wrong approach. Generally, RTL/LTR should be handled via `flex`, `flex-start`, `flex-end` etc. Those do not need any special rendition (manual or automated of 'inverted' CSS), change the `dir` on the `body` and voila! Rare special cases (not supported by RTLCSS, BTW) like image flip, are app's own concern and must not be delegated to the 3rd party.