# What is the Flexbox order property for?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, separation-of-concerns

The CSS `display: flexbox;` has the property for its flex-items `order`. I'm not sure what this property is for. Does this not conflict with the concept of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)?

Similar to HTML's `dir` attribute vs. the CSS `direction:rtl`; if the HTML `dir` is more [appropriate](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-css-markup) than the CSS `direction:rtl`, it stands to reason that so is the case with the flow, structure, and directionality.

> Because directionality is an integral part of the document structure, markup should be used to set the directionality for a document or chunk of information, or to identify places in the text where the Unicode bidirectional algorithm alone is insufficient to achieve desired directionality. [...] You should therefore use dedicated bidi markup whenever it is available. Do not simply attach CSS styling to a general element to achieve the effect.
>
> - *[Direction (LTR/RTL): What's the difference between the CSS direction and HTML direction attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375799/direction-ltr-rtl-whats-the-difference-between-the-css-direction-and-html-di)*

Not that I am complaining; I just had a project where the just changing the `order` was so easy rather than editing the HTML. But still, the question stands.

Comment: You can also use `order` to implement responsive layouts.

Comment: @AKX: Sure but the question stands!

Comment: Well, you can't edit the HTML based on media queries/breakpoints, can you? :D

Comment: This question is asking what the order property is for, not why W3C/WhatWG "decided to include it." It should not have been closed.

Comment: @TylerH It is asking for opinions (e.g. the _Why does CSS Flexbox have a Order Property?"_,  _"does this not conflict with the Separation of concerns?"_ and  _"A matter of convenience?"_), and it is also asking at least three questions (so lacks focus).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "Why does CSS Flexbox have an order property" can be interpreted multiple ways. I choose the simpler meaning, e.g. "what is this property for", while others may choose a more labored interpretation "Why did the working group decided to implement it"... something I think is a stretch, to be frank. Other interrogative statements are merely supportive of the main question, not separate distinct things worthy of considering the question in need of focus. As you can see by the answer, it's easy to completely address in a normal-length answer.

Comment: @TylerH Given the other two questions that I quoted, I think you're too generous in your interpretation. The question about separation of concerns or convenience to me clearly indicate it's a "why is it designed this way" question, and that is opinion-based.

Comment: I don't know about edits. Question had a really mood change when it was edited to "What is the Flexbox order property for?". Everybody knows what it was for. The question was very focused, direct and not opinion based at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` property is intended to allow you to place relevant content of a page (the reason someone is ostensibly on the page in the first place) first in the DOM, while still achieving certain layouts like the 'holy grail' layout (header, content, footer, with a sidebar on either side of the content) without resorting to very awkward hacks.

From the [W3C Flexbox Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-accessibility):

> Many web pages have a similar shape in the markup, with a header on top, a footer on bottom, and then a content area and one or two additional columns in the middle. Generally, it’s desirable that the content come first in the page’s source code, before the additional columns. However, this makes many common designs, such as simply having the additional columns on the left and the content area on the right, difficult to achieve. This has been addressed in many ways over the years, often going by the name "Holy Grail Layout" when there are two additional columns. order makes this trivial. For example, take the following sketch of a page’s code and desired layout:
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <header>...</header>
> <main>
>   <article>...</article>
>   <nav>...</nav>
>   <aside>...</aside>
> </main>
> <footer>...</footer>
> ```
>
> [image: image of a 'holy grail' layout]
>
> This layout can be easily achieved with flex layout:
>
> ```css
> main { display: flex; }
> main > article { order: 2; min-width: 12em; flex:1; }
> main > nav     { order: 1; width: 200px; }
> main > aside   { order: 3; width: 200px; }
> ```

This allows for faster loading of the content, which is a direct concern of user experience.

Coincidentally, it also makes it really easy to reorder flex elements for, say, [a mobile or responsive layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829567/change-div-order-with-css-depending-on-device-width/32829829#32829829). I wrote that answer to illustrate how trivial it is to do this *via CSS*. Changing the DOM order itself would require different HTML pages based on your conditions for different orders, or JavaScript. In either case, it can break assistive technology or user scripts that users might have which depend on the DOM structure. It's also more complex/more effort to maintain that vs CSS which you only have to write once.

> But does this not conflict with the Separation of concerns?

No, HTML's concern is **content**. CSS' concern is **presentation**. The *order in which sibling elements are presented on page* is a **presentation matter**, no different from whether they should display horizontally, vertically, be centered or side-aligned, etc.

For further reading, see: [Use cases for `order` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Ordering_flex_items#use_cases_for_order)